# Which US-based financial institutions offer Visa Direct?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, visa

[Visa Direct](https://arch.developer.visa.com/vpp/) ([also see here](https://usa.visa.com/dam/VCOM/download/about-visa/seminar-mwc-visa-direct-day-3.pdf)) seems to be a means of transferring money (almost instantly) to another Visa card.

Which banks support this service? I use several major and popular banks, and none of them seem to offer this "transfer to any other Visa cardholder" service.

Background: I was able to us this to clear some money out of my soon-to-be-closed Google Wallet account to my U.S. Bank checking account. The incoming transfer appeared as a pending transaction on my U.S. Bank statement as "Visa Direct". A previous cleared transaction appeared as "Visa Direct Goo*xxxxxx" (where xxxxxx is my name).

Comment: This is likely to be closed as a "shopping question".

Comment: @keshlam Really? Why would that be? This is about money transfers - there's no mention of purchases here at all.

Comment: You're "shopping" for banks with a particular service. You can probably research this as easily as we can. I'd suggest contacting Visa.

Answer (score 1):

http://dealbook.nytimes.com/2014/12/13/small-bank-in-kansas-is-a-financial-testing-ground/

Citizens Bank of Weir might allow you to do this, their experimentation in speeding up bank transfers was pushing money over the debit card network.